# MongoDB - Need help updating an Object within an Array of a Document

Tags: arrays, mongodb, object, mongoose

**Situation:**

I have a collection named 'employees'. This collection contains an array of managers. Each manager object has a property called 'directReports'. This property is an array of objects representing their subordinates. For example:

```
 db.employees.find({ name: 'John Smith' });

{
   "id" : 1234,
   "name" : "John Smith",
   "FirstName" : "John",
   "LastName" : "Smith",
   "SamAccountName" : "jsmith",
   "DepartmentName" : "Management",
   "SupID" : 0,
   "Email" : "jsmith@company.tld",
   "SupSamAccountName" : "bross",
   "SupName" : "Bob Ross",
   "directReports" : [
    {
        "id" : 5678,
        "name" : "Jane Doe",
        "FirstName" : "Jane",
        "LastName" : "Doe",
        "SamAccountName" : "jdoe",
        "DepartmentName" : "Agent",
        "SupID" : 1234,
        "Email" : "jdoe@company.tld",
        "SupSamAccountName" : "jsmith",
        "SupName" : "John Smith",
    },...]}
```

**What I'd Like to Do:**

I'd like to add a new property called 'status' (with a value of 'Lunch') to Jane Doe.

How can I do this?

Any help is extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `SamAccountName`s are unique:

```
db.employees.update({
    { SamAccountName: "jsmith", directReports.SamAccountName: "jdoe" },
    { $set: { directReports.$.status: "Lunch" } }
})
```

Based on this question's tags, since you're using Mongoose, be sure to update your schema appropriately. You might consider reworking your schema to take advantage of [Mongoose query population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

Comment: I tried running this and it gave me a syntax error:

     E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: invalid property id @(shell)

Comment: Are you using `id`s or `_id`s? I assumed `id` based on your question. By default MongoDB uses `_id` as the unique identifier, which are `ObjectId`s

Comment: I'm actually using the SamAccountName for both the manager and subordinate. I tried even using Mongo's _id but that didn't work either.

Comment: How about this: is `SamAccountName` unique across all employees?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107585/discussion-between-ggallo-and-hideokuze).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add 'status' with the value of 'launch' to your model and after create a function to update all the employees data. 
Hope it helps